# How to add an product attribute to multiple attribute sets programmatically?

Tags: magento2, attribute-set

How to add an product attribute to multiple attribute sets programmatically?

This question has been answerded for [Magento 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515932/adding-existing-attribute-to-all-attribute-sets), but how does it work with Magento 2?

**Edit:**
I create all my custom attributes in an installation script. They are created when installing magento (I add my extentions to the Magento folder before installing it on a server). At this time I don't know about the attrubute sets. They are created later during an import. So I want to assign existing custom attributes when creating an attribute set.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide a value for 'group' in the attribute configuration array the attribute will be added to that group in all attribute sets:

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'my_attribute', [
    ...
    'group' => 'General',  // or some other group name
    ...
]);
```

Comment: I create all my custom attributes in an installation script. They are created when installing magento (I add my extentions to Magento folder before installing it on a server). At this time I don't know about the attrubute sets. They are created later during an import. So I want to assign existing custom attributes when creating an attribute set.